# Can I import dataset with latent variables calculated, or do I need to define them in the syntax?

Tags: structural-equation-modeling, latent-variable, lavaan

Lavaan tells you that you need to define latent variables for the analyses, however, I have imported a dataset from SPSS where I already created the latent variables, as this is easier than doing it in R. I'm just wondering whether that is acceptable, or whether I need to go through the tedious process of defining the latent variables?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

A latent variable doesn't have values, so it can't appear in a data set. If you *estimated* values of the latent variables, called factor scores, then you're no longer dealing with latent variables. Factor scores are faulty estimates of the latent variable values and there are several problems with using them in regression and SEMs. The two biggest are that the uncertainty in their estimation is not accounted for (i.e., they are treated as fixed even though they were estimated with uncertainty), and they still contain measurement error.

So estimating a SEM with a full latent variable model in `lavaan` is absolutely preferable to estimating a SEM with factor scores. Do not use factor scores in a model when the original indicators are available.

Note that SEM doesn't involve a regression using observed variables and latent variable values; it involves proposing a model that include a hypothetical latent variable that explains why the observed variable are related as they are. The latent variable values are never estimated and they don't have to be. You don't need to know any individual's value on the latent variable to estimate the coefficients of a SEM.